# How to wait for code inside addSnapshotListener to finish execution before returning to function?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift-framework

```
    func getStudents() {
        var student: Student = Student()
        db.collection(StudentViewModel.studentCollection).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("ERROR | Getting Student Documents in Firestore Service: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                // no documents
                print("No documents to fetch!")
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                var updatedStudentDocuments: [Student] = [Student]()
                for studentDocument in snapshot.documents {
                    student = Student(id: studentDocument.documentID,
                                                    name: studentDocument.data()["name"] as? String ?? "")
                    
                    updatedStudentDocuments.append(student)
                }
                
                self.students = updatedStudentDocuments
            }
        }
    }
```

Every time I run this function and check what's inside *self.students*, I find that it's empty. That's because the function *getStudents* is returning before the closure in *addSnapshotListener* finishes executing. How do I make the *getStudents* function wait for the closure to finish executing before continuing its own execution?

Comment: The snapshot listener will run whenever the result of the query changes.  You'll add this listener each time the function is invoked.

Comment: swift to `async await`

Comment: Do you want to get the students each time the function is called or do you want to call the function one time and let the snapshot listener constantly return changes to students?

Comment: @danh so apparently the snapshot listener did not run the first time I called the function getStudents(). Is it supposed to act this way? If yes, how do I make it run the first time?

Comment: The closure will always run after the getStudents.  You sort of have to embrace the async. If the caller needs students to be set before continuing, have the caller pass a closure that is invoked by getStudents()